# Cannot run program due to "device is not ready" error

Tags: dll, c++, matlab

I have a 32bit `Matlab` `mex` function that was linked against [**OpenDDS** libraries](http://www.opendds.org/) as well as my own custom ones. I made a `Visual Studio 2010` setup project to deploy the necessary dlls to other machines. I've been able to run this `mex` function with no problem in a number of machines (32bit and 64bit Windows 7 machines). However, there is one machine that gives me a `**device is not ready**` error message when I attempt to run the `mex` function.

My guess is that there is an issue when loading the dlls, but I'm not sure what could be the problem. I've checked for missing dlls or incompatible `VS C++ 2010 redistributable package` in the machine, but everything looks OK (I would get a different error message if this was the case). I've tried to run my application in safe mode in case other programs were doing something unexpected but this did not work.

I have tried to find more information about what the error message `**device is not ready**` means. What could be the problem?